# How do I deal with timing when writing Selenium Scripts that go through many pages?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

I hope this question isn't too general. Well, the situation is that I am testing a web-app and I am ending up having to put these delays with the `setSpeed` command. But I'd rather say to it "wait for the page to finish loading", except I can't exactly do that.. because it gets redirected to a page with a random URL.

Here's a sample of it(sorry it looks a bit ugly):

```
setSpeed    7000    

open    router2/default.aspx?SID=9795d782-07d9-4fcc-a896-f79e30b2b800&FIRID=10DULKAR&SUMSTAT=1&PID=     

setSpeed    700     

click   xpath=(//input[@name='radio_43'])[2]    

setSpeed    4000    

clickAndWait    id=ctl00_Content_btnContinue    

setSpeed    7000    

verifyTextPresent   Post Qualification Logic    

clickAndWait    id=ctl00_Content_btnContinue    

type    name=numeric_42     19

clickAndWait    id=ctl00_Content_btnContinue    

click   xpath=(//input[@name='radio_51'])[5]    

clickAndWait    id=ctl00_Content_btnContinue    

click   xpath=(//input[@name='radio_2180'])[4]  

clickAndWait    id=ctl00_Content_btnContinue    

verifyTextPresent   Client Survey Entry
```

That's why I put the 7 second delays in it. but it seems slow/inefficient.

thanks

Comment: thanks so much Pinny, nice link I am on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on if you are using standard HTTP redirection, or javascript/ajax execution. For standard redirection, the 'clickAndWait' commands should suffice without setting any delays. And for ajax execution, use the wait_for_ajax trick as demonstrated [here](http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/selenium-wait-for-ajax-the-right-way/)